# cs50 pset 3, printing winner function not working

Tags: c, cs50

```
// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    float votes2win;
    //Votes could be odd number so would need to be rounded
    int rounded_votes;

    votes2win = voter_count / 2;
    rounded_votes = round(votes2win);

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > rounded_votes)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

need to print winner cant seem to find the problem in this function is it the function or something else in my code?

Comment: if you undelete it and accept my answer, you will receive some reputation and my upvote on the question outweighs the downvotes anyway. So yes, you should undelete the question. The reason you got downvotes it you did not provide enough context for your code.  Try and take more time explaining what you do and what problem you encounter.  This applies to this question too.

Comment: brilliant also ive been trying to use your code to make my own code but its very challenging if i used your code would it be considered cheating or not?

Comment: If you use it directly, that could be considered cheating, but you can study my code and see how to fix and improve yours, that's not cheating, just the normal course of studying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a runoff election with 3 voters, this function will only print candidates who have 3 votes because of the use of `round`. Exploit the fact that C truncates integer division.

Comment: So helpful Mr, I solved it literally moments after your comment I appreciate the help, cant believe I didn't realise my fault, thank you so much and for not giving me the answer it would have made it a lot harder as I cant use anything handed to me so Id have to think of a whole new function, your a great Dino lol !!!!!!! @DinoCoderSaurus